# Fedora 13 constantly reboots on an HP Z400

Tags: linux, fedora, reboot, fedora-13

I just installed Fedora 13 on an HP Z400, and it's stuck in an endless reboot loop (lives 2 seconds before rebooting).  It's a 64-bit machine and seems to meet all the hardware requirements.  Any idea what could be wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the BIOS -- HP has a special BIOS for Linux.  Installing that solved my problems with Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing fedora 13 a couple months back and had a similar issue if i remember.  I think it turned out to be that the installation wasn't exactly valid.  Try downloading from another source, or re-downloading the file and then installing fedora again.  That's what I did to get it to work.